# Undefined reference to declared in *.h already declared in another *.h

Tags: c

I have a Type def ListHndl declared in my list.h which is a pointer to a list in list.c. I have a graph.c that uses the ListHndl type in a function but my graph.h sees the ListHndl type as an undefined reference. I have #included the list.h and graph.h in my graph.c file. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Having some code to look at will be useful.

Comment: Have `graph.h` include `list.h`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include list.h in graph.h,and only include graph.h in graph.c

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that the #includes in my .c were in the wrong order so the graph.h couldn't use the list.h.